# Rails One table has multiple foreign keys with different columns of any other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a table of access_list and in members table there are multiple foreign keys of the access_lists like mobile_access_list_id email_access_list_id first_name_access_list_id. How can I manage such associations in rails 4.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: i have tried some thing like this: belongs_to :access_list,:class_name => "AccessList" , :foreign_key => "email_access_id" but its not working when i tried in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# app/models/access_list.rb
class AccessList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
end

# app/models/member.rb
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :email_access_list, class_name: 'AccessList', foreign_key: 'email_access_id'
  belongs_to :mobile_access_list, class_name: 'AccessList', foreign_key: 'mobile_access_id'
  belongs_to :first_name_access_list, class_name: 'AccessList', foreign_key: 'first_name_access_id'
end
```

The code you posted in your comment `belongs_to :access_list,:class_name => "AccessList" , :foreign_key => "email_access_id"` is going to create an assocation `access_list` just for `email_access_list` and not for `mobile_access_list`.  The only problem here I believe is naming of the association.  `access_list` is a generic name and it might have confused you!

So, the point to note is that you want to define different associations for different foreign keys, of course depending on your need for for that association.